# how to query multiple select using IN with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

how would you do this using pdo

```
        $post = Array
 (
 [0] => 558
[1] => 494
[2] => 469
[3] => 459
[4] => 452
[5] => 451
 )
   $ids =  implode(',' post);
   mysql_query('Select *  where post IN ('$ids'));
```

currently i'm doing

```
$query = "Select * where post in (:ids);";
$stmt = $pdo=>prepare($query);
$stmt =>execute(array('ids'=> $ids);
```

but this does not seem too work

Comment: Are you trying `where in ` condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem to be invalid.Try like this :

```
$array=array("558","494","469","459","452","451");
$in_list = "'".implode("','",$array)."'";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('Select * FROM table where post IN ('.$in_list.')');
$stmt->execute();
```

For detail about prepare statement you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: can you explain using my example

Comment: Check now with edits, you didn't provide `Table Name` to the query.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman you are directly inserting the array into the query, which defeats the purpose of `->prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically build your placeholders `?`

```
$post = Array(....);
//count $post size, repeat a string of '?,'
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($post) - 1) . '?';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE post IN ($in);";
$stmt = $pdo=>prepare($query);
$stmt =>execute($post);
```